# get Email Address from contact list

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I getting contact list by

permission

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

but how to get Email address from

```
 public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//what should i have to write to fetch email address of selected contact
// I wrote like below but i could not get result

 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
     try{
             Uri contactData = data.getData();

             Cursor cursorEmail = getContentResolver().query(contactData,null,null,null,null);
             cursorEmail.moveToFirst();
             String emailAdd =  cursorEmail.getString(cursorEmail.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
             Toast.makeText(MySettings.this, emailAdd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }catch(Exception e){
              Toast.makeText(MySettings.this, "No Email Add found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

}
```

but the problem is that i am not getting Email address from selected contact list so can any one give me solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use following code to retrieve email.

```
public ArrayList<String> ShowContact() {        

    nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
            phoneList = new ArrayList<String>();
            emailList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer
                    .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                // Query phone here. Covered next

                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // Do something with phones
                    String phoneNo = pCur
                            .getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    nameList.add(name); // Here you can list of contact.
                        phoneList.add(phoneNo); // Here you will get list of phone number.                  


                    Cursor emailCur = cr.query( 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                            new String[]{id}, null); 
                        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
        String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));                            

                 emailList.add(email); // Here you will get list of email    

                        } 
                        emailCur.close();       
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }

    return nameList; // here you can return whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: hello Akshay sir i have used your code but still getting error 
 Cursor cursorContacts = managedQuery(contactData,  null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
      String id = cursorContacts.getString(cursorContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
      Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",new String[]{id}, null);

Comment: @user1545066 What is the error.If you are testing it on emulator then make sure that you have added contact with email address in the emulator.

Comment: @user1545066 I have changed my post please find the changes.And let me know is it working or not.

Comment: I want to retrieve only selected record from list. Because i got multiple records in list.Please provide solution.

Answer (score 2):

function for fetch email id of selected contact

```
private void retrieveContactEmail()
{
    Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
        new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
        null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {
        contactID = cursorID.getString(
            cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
        new String[]{contactID}, null);

    int emailIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String emailg = cursor.getString(emailIdx);

        if(emailg!=null) {
            email.setText(emailg);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this,
                "No email id for this contact",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
String emailAdd =  cursorEmail.getString(cursorEmail.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
```

instead of

```
String emailAdd =  cursorEmail.getString(cursorEmail.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
```